# "Failed to create java" on running Windows service

Tags: java, windows

I have a java application, which has to run as windows service.
I am able to install the service using the following command.

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --StartClass %STARTER% --StopClass %STOPPER% %START_PARAMS% %STOP_PARAMS%
```

The service is installed successfully but when i try to run it it shows Failed to create java. path also it is not showing in the jkartha log file.

I have `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing to jdk1.5.
and even i copied `msvcr71.dll` to windows\system32 folder and restarted the PC.

I am running this on windows 2008 server.

I didn't install apache tomcat server. `prunsrv.exe` and `procmgr.exe` i just copied.

Please suggest me how i need to overcome this problem.

whether to run application as windows service, prunsrv.exe, prunmgr.exe are enough is it? I am able to successfully install but not able to start why???

Comment: Looks like the parameters that are being passed to the java executable are not right. Do you see any more details in the system error logs?

Comment: I must say that even though i have no idea, i do not understand why you aren't using an IDE like eclipse to solve all these problems. and your on windows even, there is nothing simpler

Comment: It would be easier, if you could post the whole resolved command

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Installation is successfully, i able to see the service in the list of services from service.msc But when right click then say start, it is failing.

Comment: Service IDEV installed
.Procrun finished.Updating service...[info] Service IDEV updated .Update service finished.
.Procrun finished.
.Updating service...
. Service IDEV  [info] Service IDEV updated  [info] Update service finished.
.Procrun finished.
[info] Running Service...
[info] Starting service...
[886  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java 
[1120 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1 [info] Run service finished.[info] Procrun finished.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [set your service to run as the user that installed Java](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService), otherwise it won't find its environment variables.

If you must run in the default Local System account, then you can run a batch file that sets up the environment and then launches java.exe.

Comment: Thanks all for replying.. I got the solution for it. I double clicked the java.exe file, then it will show the properties window. In that go to "java" tab. Deselect the "use default" and specify explicity jvm path till jvm.dll. Then it worked.